# Postgres drop type XX000 "cache lookup failed for type"

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently working on a PostgreSQL 9.2.x Database with a lots of Clients, and tables and functions. We deploy code constantly and sometimes it is necessary to even drop a type or a function due this deployment.

Example:

1.Script to create the needed functions in the first place

```
CREATE TYPE tmp._myEnum AS ENUM ('OLD', 'NEW', 'BOTH'); 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tmp._get_status()
RETURNS tmp._myEnum AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN 'OLD'::tmp._myEnum;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER COST 10;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tmp._my_testfunction()
RETURNS VOID AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    CASE tmp._get_status()
        WHEN 'OLD'::tmp._myEnum THEN 
            RAISE INFO 'myEnum is OLD';
        WHEN 'NEW'::tmp._myEnum THEN 
            RAISE INFO 'myEnum is NEW';
        WHEN 'BOTH'::tmp._myEnum THEN 
            RAISE INFO 'myEnum is BOTH';
        ELSE
            RAISE INFO 'myEnum has an unexpected value';
    END CASE;

    FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
        RAISE INFO 'Step [%]',i;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER COST 10;
```

2.Scenario that leads to the exception:

a)One Client is constantly using tmp._my_testfunction() like this

```
SELECT tmp._my_testfunction()
```

b)In order to deploy a change to the Composite type i execute in another session

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS tmp._get_status();
DROP TYPE IF EXISTS tmp._myEnum;

CREATE TYPE tmp._myEnum AS ENUM ('OLD', 'NEW', 'BOTH','NOTHING'); 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tmp._get_status()
RETURNS tmp._myEnum AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    RETURN 'OLD'::tmp._myEnum;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER COST 10;
```

c)The Client that is constantly using tmp._my_testfunction() imidiatly throws

```
ERROR:  cache lookup failed for type 386318
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function tmp._my_testfunction() line 3 at CASE
```

How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we couldn't find another way to work around this  Problem we've implemented a solution that notifies all other connections to refresh itself by using LISTEN and NOTIFY commands. So all Clients are listening on specific channels for a command that tells them to reconnect. The command ist then send in the same Transaction that dropes the type.

Answer (score 2):

What seems to be the case here is a race condition. Your clients calls `tmp._my_test_function()` and while that is being set up by interpreting the source code of the function, you drop the function and the `enum` type and then re-create them. Internally, virtually all objects are referenced by their `oid` (with a value of 386318 for the type in your case) so the function and the `enum` in your client function resolve to `oid`s. If the interpreter resolves the function and the `enum` to two `oid`s and you then drop the function and the `enum` and re-create them, the old `oid`s disappear and your newly created function and `enum` get different `oid`s. New invocations of the function will work because the interpreter finds the new `oid`s for the function and the `enum`.

A solution in a scenario like this would be to `REVOKE EXECUTE` on the client function, make the changes and then `GRANT EXECUTE` the privileges again. On the client side you would have to deal with privilege errors by retrying the function call until you succeed.

In general, you would deploy new code on a production server during low-traffic periods and/or through session management if you want to avoid the overhead of retrying function calls.

Comment: we are already deploying only in the hours of low traffic but due to the consumer traffic on our product, its still seems to be to much for a clean deployment. Isn't there any command or way to notify Postgres to flush all session caches ?  problem here was that the exception was thrown even 20 minutes after the deployment and stoped only after all db connections have been closed and opened again.

Comment: You could use an advisory lock but then you would have to put that on every (block of multiple) function(s) and every query using any such function would have to obtain the advisory lock prior to invoking the function. That appears to be overkill to me. The best suggestion I have is to take your question to the DBA forum, as that is where the back-end experts hangout.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try my luck over there. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty untechnical solution...

I had my app deployed on AWS and remotely logged into PSQL, dropped the database, reimported and was presented with the above.

Redeploying the application resolved it, why I'm not sure.